# How to sum multiple columns using a single formula in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

The data that i have is in a 2D fashion [image: Data Representation]

I want the output in this type of schema using a **Single Formula!**

[image: Desired Output]

I've tried PIVOT and SUMIF,SUMIFS,QUERY functions. But, Alas unable to figure out the same. Can anyone please help me with this

Comment: Do NOT share [spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455)/[images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) as the only source of data, to avoid closure of the question. Make sure to add input and expected output as **plain text table** to the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easier to copy/paste as well**. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: The "issue" for pivot is that your data format (2d) doesnt ideally fit the pivot method: 

Pivot usually prefers data as somewhat of a list: 

```
Alex North Shirt 764
Alex North Shoes 689
...
Hanna South Shoes 788
```

if you have that format then pivot should work: 
https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9308944?hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT for this task.

Formula `B12` dragged right and down:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($B$5:$I$8*($A$5:$A$8=$A12)*($B$3:$I$3=B$11))
```

Result:

[image]

Pay attention at all those $ when adapting to your ranges.

Comment: Thanks bruv! The solution works wonder

Answer (score 1):

you can also try this ***single*** formula to create the `summary` table.

```
=LAMBDA(x,y,{{"",y};x,MAKEARRAY(COUNTA(x),COUNTA(y),LAMBDA(r,c,SUM(FILTER(FILTER(B3:I,B1:I1=INDEX(y,,c)),A3:A=INDEX(x,r)))))})(FILTER(A3:A,A3:A<>""),UNIQUE(FILTER(B1:I1,B1:I1<>""),1))
```

- 

[image]